# Rest Assured API testing - Pass a Json Object as parameter to a get request

Tags: rest, testing, junit, parameter-passing, rest-assured

**REST Assured Testing -**
**How to use delete request to delete the Workspace from this url**

http://in-kumaran2-1:8080/devops-workbench-web/rest/api/workspace/delete/{projectId}

given the request

```
given().when().delete(url,JSON body);
```

Where Sample Request JSON body is given below

> {"name":"newworkspace","workspaceFlow":"Open
>   Sorce","versionControl":"SVN","featureManagement":"JIRA","defectManagement":"","buildAutomation":"Selenium","deploymentAutomation":"","buildRepository":"Nexus","codeQualityTools":"SonarQube","automatedTestingTools":"Selenium","environmentProvision":"Puppet","environmentConfiguration":"Puppet",**"projectId":{"id":"56cebe578850d51c6fe07684","name":"wbproject","description":"wbproject","processTemplate":"Agile","projectManager":"Anil","projectStartDate":1454284800000,"projectEndDate":1475193600000,"remarks":null,"accountId":{"id":"56cebe218850d51c6fe07683","accountName":"workbench","accountDescription":"workbench
>   account"}}**}

projectID has another Object {"id": "56cebe578850d51c6fe07684" ....} How to pass this projectId in the delete Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL is: http://example.com/building

**My Query Strings are :**

globalDates:{"startMs":1473672973818,"endMs":1481448973817,"period":90}
limitTo:6
loadTvData:true
startFrom:0
userId:5834fb36981baacb6a876427

**Way to pass Query String Parameters in GET url using Rest Assured like this :-**

when() .parameter("globalDates","startMs","1474260058054","endMs","1482036058051","period","90")

.parameters("limitTo","6")

.parameters("loadTvData","true")

.parameters("startFrom","0")

.parameters("userId","5834fb36981baacb6a876427");

Answer (score 1):

actually, i have passed json object like below:

```
Response res =given().
            content(jo). //jo is the json object to pass with the url.
            with().
            contentType("application/json").
            header("Content-Type", "application/json").
    when().
            post(settings.getApiUrl()); //this is the url, i use post method
```

and jo is something like this:

```
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
jo.addProperty("username", "abc");//key and value
jo.addProperty("password", "abc");//key and value
```

u may try something like this.i used here as header u may send it as param.